# Command not found error

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to type the `make` command at the command-prompt, but I keep getting the following error:

> `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch file`.

I am a novice and have no clue about these things, but I read lots of websites about this problem and I tried to follow their advices, but it's still not working.

I am using a Dell laptop with Windows 7 64-bit. I am running it from this folder:

```
C:\Users\Jenn\Documents\PhD\Software\trimAl\source
```

My path is

```
C:\Perl\site\bin
C:\Perl\bin
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\
c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64
C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card\Driver
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The `make` command is a programming tool that builds a project. It does not come with Windows, it comes with a programming environment of some sort that you have to install manually. What are you trying to build; are you trying to compile a Perl script?

Answer (score 4):

### Plan A

Find where `make.exe` is hiding and add it to your PATH.

### Plan B

Install `make` (for example [this one](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm))

### Plan B.2

Install the compilers and other stuff that are also usually needed for make to do anything useful. Have a look in your `Makefile` in `C:\Users\Jenn\Documents\PhD\Software\trimAl\source` or read the documentation for whatever you have downloaded in there.

### Plan C

Find a precompiled Windows executable (preferably with a self-installer) of whatever thing you seek instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `make` command in Windows.  If you have some versions of Visual Studio installed,  you may have a program named `nmake`, which is Windows' version of the classic UNIX `make` utility.

Answer (score 0):

"Make" isn't an in-build Windows utility or command, hence it's telling you "'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch file".

You'll need the 3rd party `Make.exe`; which one will depend on what it is you're actually trying to accomplish.